# Passing data between two ViewControllers (delegate) - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog, segue

I have two `ViewController's.`

1. `FirstVC` - I have `label` and `button` with segue "modal"
2. `SecondVC` - I have `PickerView` and `button` (back to FirstVC):

   ```
   @IBAction func bntback(sender: AnyObject) {
             self.dissmissViewControllerAnimatied(true, completion: nil)
       }
   ```

And I created delegate in `SecondViewController` as:

```
protocol SendDataDelegate {
   func sendData(text:String)
}
```

Next:

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
      var delegate: SendDataDelegate!
      var firstvc = FirstVC()
      var arr = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
      @IBOutlet var pickview: UIPickerView!
      override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         pickview.dataSource = self
         pickview.selegate = self
     }
```

My function of `PickerView` and in this function I use my delegate as:

```
func pickerView (pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
  var text = arr[row]
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_quene(), {
  self.delegate.sendData(text)//there is an error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
  )}
}
```

FirstVC:

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController, SendDataDelegate {
      var data = SecondVC()
      //....
      override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.data.delegate = self
     }
     func sendData (text:String) {
        mylable.text = text
        //or 
        //var txt = text
       //mylable.text = txt
     }
 }
```

Help me please with this problem.

Comment: `var data = SecondVC()` cannot work because there is already an instance of SecondVC created in Interface Builder.

The usual way to set the delegate is in prepareForSegue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) You need to set delegate into prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondVC {
        viewController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

2) Set `delegate` as Optional

```
class SecondVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    var delegate: SendDataDelegate?
    ...

    func pickerView (pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        var text = arr[row]
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_quene(), {
            self.delegate?.sendData(text)
        )}
    }
```