# Swift 4.2: Can't get simple delegate protocol working

Tags: ios, swift

[YouTube Screenrecord of my workflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uy06Tm_voFI&feature=youtu.be)

**FirstViewController**

```swift
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
        secondViewController.delegate = self
    }
}

extension FirstViewController: DataEnteredDelegate {
    func userDidEnterInformation(info: String) {
        label.text = info
        print("label changed")
    }
}
```

**SecondViewController**

```swift
import UIKit

protocol DataEnteredDelegate: class {
    func userDidEnterInformation(info: String)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func sendTextBackButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("button tapped")
        delegate?.userDidEnterInformation(info: textField.text!)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not implemented protocol methods

Comment: first remove `as! DataEnteredDelegate`

Comment: where did you push the second view controller ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37203430/6630644

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075116/passing-data-between-two-viewcontrollers-delegate-swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between two ViewControllers (delegate) - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075116/passing-data-between-two-viewcontrollers-delegate-swift)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Examples of Delegates in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501780/examples-of-delegates-in-swift)

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the missing delegate adoption

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, DataEnteredDelegate {
```

it **cannot** work if the view controllers are designed in a storyboard.

The line

```
let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
```

creates a brand new instance of `SecondViewController` which is **not** the instance in the storyboard and all outlets are **not** connected.

You have to use a [segue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboardsegue) or you have to [instantiate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/1616214-instantiateviewcontroller) and present the second view controller to get the real reference to the destination controller.

**Note:**

In terms of Swift protocol/delegate to share data between controllers is quite *objective-c-ish*.
Callback closures are more light-weight and *swiftier*.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the first view controller to

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, DataEnteredDelegate {
...
}
```

The reason is that the first view controller didn't implement the protocol so the cast cound't happen

Comment: thank you!! i missed that, fixed it but it's still not working (see updated post)

Answer (score 1):

Implement your protocol to your first view controller. Good practice is to extend controller and then put protocol’s delegate methods to this extension

```
extension FirstViewController: DataEnteredDelegate {
    func userDidEnterInformation(info: String) {
        ...
    }
}
```

next, second view controller which you’re setting its delegate isn’t probably controller which you’re presenting later on. To set delegate correctly, set delegate of controller which will be presented. If you’re using segues, override `prepare(for:sender:)` and set delegate of downcasted segue’s destination. If you’re presenting view controller manually or you’re pushing it, set delegate of this controller which you’re presenting/pushing.

Comment: thanks you very much! I've moved the code snippet to the extension and fixed the other errors. I don't push or segue (see updated post video), i just want to update the first viewController manually from the second.

Comment: @AmandaGarcia read the answer more carefully. I described why your code doesn’t work

Answer (score 0):

Check this and update.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, DataEnteredDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    func userDidEnterInformation(info: String) {
        label.text = info
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
        secondViewController.delegate = self 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i see that i initially missed the DataEnteredDelegate as super class. i fixed it, but it does not seem to work (see updated post)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for FirstView Controller

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, DataEnteredDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    func userDidEnterInformation(info: String) {
        label.text = info
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
        secondViewController.delegate = self
    }

    func userDidEnterInformation(info: String){
      // do your stuff here
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i see that i initially missed the DataEnteredDelegate as super class. i fixed it, but it does not seem to work (see updated post)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are facing this issue since you are setting the delegate to nil.

try setting it like this:

```js
    weak var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate? = FirstViewController.self as! DataEnteredDelegate
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct init of  SecondViewController is not acceptable here. Besides, After the two steps the secondViewController will be released and not existing.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let secondViewController = SecondViewController() // Not the right way to initialize!
    secondViewController.delegate = self. //secondViewController  will be released!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, you are creating a new `SecondViewController` instead of the actual one used by the tab bar. You need to access the second view controller that is being used by the `UITabBarController` instead of allocating a new instance, for that change your `viewDidLoad` implementation to:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let secondViewController      = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.last as? SecondViewController
    secondViewController.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your rootViewController of UIWndow is UITabBarController Which is visible on YouTube video link you share so that you need to get SecoundViewController from that place using this code snippet

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let rootController = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    if let viewControllers = rootController.viewControllers {
        if viewControllers.count > 0 {
            if let secondViewController = viewControllers[1] as? SecondViewController {
                secondViewController.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

So that your delegate will not nil.

In your current solution your `SecondViewController` get new instance but not loaded from storyboard and you got nil in delegate so that delegate method not able to call.

```
// you have nil refrence to delegate check it here
if (self.delegate != nil) {
    self.delegate?.userDidEnterInformation(info: textField.text ?? "")
}
```

hope it help.